# Reference the main view controller... need the code

Tags: objective-c

I have a view based app (not navigation or tab based...)

My main view controller is called from the app delegate and initiated from a xib.

Then I use presentModalViewController to bring another view on the screen with it's own xib and view controller.

I have no problems passing data to that view controller.

However, when I dismiss the second view controller, I want to send data back to the main view controller for my app, but I just can't figure out how to reference it.   Actually, I'd like to call a method in the main view controller if possible.

I've been struggling with this a bit and have found suggestions online but I just can't seem to get it to work.   I'm hoping someone can provide the sample code to do this.

P.s. is this "main view controller" still referred to as a "root view controller" or is that term only used when dealing with a view controller stack (i.e. navigation or tab view controller)

EDIT:
I'm sure Bryan's solution would work so I have accepted as answer.  However I ended up using NSNotificationCenter to get this to work and I find it a bit simpler to understand as a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the delegation pattern. In your modal view controller's header file, create an interface for a new delegate protocol...

```
@protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)sendData:(Data *)someData;

@end
```

...and give your `ModalViewController` a new instance variable that implements this protocol:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Your main view controller should implement this protocol...

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <ModalViewControllerDelegate> {
```

...and set itself as the delegate before it presents the modal view controller:

```
ModalViewController *modalViewController = [[[ModalViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[modalViewController setDelegate:self];
// Present modal view controller
```

The main view controller should implement the delegate protocol's method:

```
- (void)sendData:(Data *)someData {
    NSLog("I have just received some data: %@", someData);
}
```

Then inside your modal view controller, you can simply call the following method whenever you want to send data back to the main view controller:

```
[delegate sendData:someData];
```

Comment: To answer your P.S. question, I think it is correct to refer to your "main view controller" as the "root view controller" in this instance. You'll see here in the documentation that `UIWindow` has a `rootViewController` property which is used to set the window's view: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html

Comment: Hey Brian, trying to get this to work...  I added the ModalViewControllerDelegate interface to the ModalViewController.h file  (I added above the ModalViewController interface).   Then I implemented the protocol in MainViewController as described.  However, when I add the property in ModalViewController.h I get error "Cannot find protocol declaration for "ModalViewControllerDelegate"

Comment: Either move the `ModalViewControllerDelegate` interface declaration above the `ModalViewController` interface declaration in the header file, or add `@protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate;` up top along with the rest of your import statements.